# Неправильная работа sscanf для спецификатора %n?

Tags: c++, c, scanf

Столкнулся с проблемой(или это норма?) при написании кода для парсинга строки с числами.
Функция sscanf, если исходить из мануалов, должна записывать количество уже обработанных ею символов в аргумент, который соответствует спецификатору %n. Но, оказывается, что если строкой форматирования задан некоторый символ, а вместо него идет другой, то счетчик в аргумент не записывается. Хотя предыдущие спецификаторы были обработаны и счетчик набирал значение.
Например

```
    unsigned char c = 0;
    int n = 0;
    char str[10] = "30\0";
    res = sscanf(str+pos,"%d% %n", &c, &n);
```

Для такой строки прочитается число, но количество прочитанных символов 'n' окажется равным нулю. Потому, что следующим символом ожидается пробел, а идет '\0'.
А здесь

```
char str2[100];
int n = 0;
int nn =0;
int res = 0;
unsigned int c = 0;

char str[1000] = "30 10.5 1.123e-50 45 46.555 200 300 500 500.100 233.100";
res = sscanf(str+pos, "%d%n%[.e0-9+-]%n"  , &c,&n, str2, &nn);
```

После выполнения n примет значение 2, а nn останется равным нулю. Так как для первого числа нет дробной части, то в 'nn' ничего не записывается. Для дробных чисел(если выполнить) всё выполняется нормально: n принимает значение исходя из суммы "предшествующий пробел+целая часть", nn становится равным " n + точка+символы после неё".
Встретился с таким поведением в gcc компиляторе. Это нормальная работа? Почему такое происходит?

Comment: Не забывайте ставить галочку слева от ответа, если он решил вопрос

Answer (score 7):

Давайте разбираться.

```
unsigned char c = 0;
int n = 0;
char str[] = "30\0";
int res = sscanf(str,"%d% %n", &c, &n);
```

Поведение данного кода неопределено по следующим причинам:

1. Спецификатор преобразования `%d` означает, что функция `sscanf` ожидает получить указатель на `int`, а вы передаёте ей указатель на `unsigned char`.
2. Используется неправильный спецификатор преобразования `"% "`. Пробел не может следовать непосредственно за символом `%`.

Изменим тип переменной `c` на `int`, и уберём символ `%` перед пробелом:

```
int c = 0;
int n = 0;
char str[] = "30\0";
int res = sscanf(str,"%d %n", &c, &n);
```

Функция `sscanf` будет обрабатывать строку `str` следующим образом:

1. Спецификатор преобразования `%d` говорит функции `sscanf` считать целое знаковое десятичное число. Что она и делает, и сохраняет результат в переменную `c`, в которой теперь хранится значение `30`. Количество считанных символов из входной строки равно `2`. Количество присвоенных значений равно `1`.
2. Директива `" "` говорит, что нужно считать все пробельные символы до тех пор пока не появится непробельный символ, либо пока не доберёмся до конца входного потока. Концом входного потока для функции `sscanf` служит нулевой символ `\0`. В данном случае между символами `"30"` и символом `\0` никаких пробельных символов нет, поэтому директива `" "` не считывает из входного потока ни одного символа. Если какая-либо директива не считывает ни единого символа, то считается, что произошла ошибка при выполнении директивы, и функция завершает свою работу. Однако, директива `" "` особенная: она никогда не завершается ошибкой. Функция продолжает свою работу.
3. Спецификатор преобразования `%n` говорит, что нужно записать в целочисленную знаковую переменную типа `int` количество считанных из входного потока символов. На данный момент считано всего два символа. Это значение и записывается в переменную `n`.
4. Функция возвращает количество присвоенных значений. Так как присваивания, задаваемые спецификатором `%n` не учитываются, то функция вернёт `1`.

Итого ([gcc](https://ideone.com/rZa936), [clang](https://ideone.com/Yxtfw2), [vc](https://rextester.com/STMMBF69626)):

```
c   == 30
n   == 2
res == 1
```

---

Теперь рассмотрим код:

```
char str2[100] = {5, 6, 7};
int n = 0;
int nn = 0;
unsigned int c = 0;

char str[] = "30 10.5 1.123e-50 45 46.555 200 300 500 500.100 233.100";
int res = sscanf(str, "%d%n%[.e0-9+-]%n"  , &c,&n, str2, &nn);
```

Здесь также имеется несоответствие спецификатора преобразования и фактически передаваемого аргумента. Функция `sscanf` ожидает, что переменная `c` имеет тип `int`, но она имеет тип `unsigned int`. Дабы избежать неопределённого поведения, изменим тип переменной `c` на `int`:

```
int c = 0;
```

Обработка строки `str` будет происходить следующим образом:

1. Выполняется спецификатор преобразования `%d`. В переменную `c` записывается значение `30`. Количество присвоенных значений равно `1`. Количество считанных символов равно `2`.
2. Выполняется спецификатор преобразования `%n`. В переменную `n` записывается количество считанных символов, т.е. `2`. Количество присвоенных значений остаётся неизменным.
3. Выполняется спецификатор преобразования `%[.e0-9+-]`. Данный спецификатор **не игнорирует** ведущие пробельные символы. А за считанными символами `"30"` как раз следует пробел. Функция `sscanf` сверяет пробел с маской и не находит соответствия. Таким образом, в процессе выполнения спецификатора преобразования `%[.e0-9+-]` ни один символ входного потока не считывается. Следовательно, функция `sscanf` считает, что произошла ошибка, и поэтому прекращает свою работу.

Итого ([gcc](https://ideone.com/5Mfz6R), [clang](https://ideone.com/7GzxOM), [vc](https://rextester.com/RVVIU20979)):

```
c   == 30
n   == 2
str == {5, 6, 7, ...}
nn  == 0
res == 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Да, всё нормально, так и должно быть: строка форматирования scanf представляет собой последовательность директив, которые обрабатываются последовательно. Если ввод не соответствует тому, что требует очередная директива, то `scanf` сразу завершается, возвращая количество элементов, обработанных успешно.

Так строка форматирования `"%d %n"`¹ представляет из себя 3 директивы: `%d`,   и `%n`. `scanf` читает число и записывает его в значение типа `int`, переданному по указателю, затем согласно директиве   считывается ноль или более пробельных символов², а затем `%n` заносится количество уже прочитанных символов, по очередному указателю.

С `%d%n%[.e0-9+-]%n` ситуация аналогична: читается `%d`, затем согласно `%n` записывается количество обработанных символов. А затем `%[.e0-9+-]` ожидает один из заданных символов, хотя во вводе оказывается пробел, что приводит к завершению `scanf`. Стоит помнить, что спецификаторы `%c`, `%[` и `%n` в отличии от других не вычитывают начальные пробелы при вводе строки.

---

<sub>¹ я так понимаю, то что в вопросе `"%d% %n"` — это опечатка т.к. `"% "` формально является нестандартным спецификатором ввода, но т.к. ни одна платформа AFAIK не поддерживает что-либо подобное, то это UB.`</sub>

<sub>² В ответе была ошибка. правильная картина изложена в ответе *@wololo*</sub>

Comment: Я бы акцентировал в ответе, что **`%c`, `%[` и `%n` в отличии от других не вычитывают начальные пробелы при вводе строки**